# How not use CoordinateMapper every time for background removing (KINECT 2)

Tags: c#, optimization

I use DepthFrame, ColorFrame and BodyIndexFrame (Kinect v2.0) for implementation background removal algorithm. But by one index (eg, 3) we obtain pixels from ColorFrame and DepthFrame (or BodyIndexFrame) which don't match in space as i know. To combine the coordinates I use the following code:

```
CoordinateMapper.MapColorFrameToDepthSpaceUsingIntPtr(
                    depthFrameData.UnderlyingBuffer,
                    depthFrameData.Size,
                    this.ColorMappedToDepthPoints);
```

However, this function does not return the correct indexes once, it only depth points return. So then you need passing through the array of color pixel recalculate depth  index each time:

```
 for (int colorY = 0; colorY < ColorSensorHeight; colorY ++)
 {
      for (int colorX = 0; colorX < ColorSensorWidth; colorX++)
      {
          int colorIndex = ((int)Math.Floor(colorY) * ColorSensorWidth) + (int)Math.Floor(colorX);

           DepthSpacePoint depthPoint = data.ColorMappedToDepthPoints[colorIndex];

           int depthX = (int)Math.Floor(depthPoint.X + 0.5);
           int depthY = (int)Math.Floor(depthPoint.Y + 0.5);

           if ((depthX >= 0) && (depthX < DepthSensorWidth) && (depthY >= 0) && (depthY < DepthSensorHeight))
           {
                    int depthIndex = (depthY * DepthSensorWidth) + depthX;

                    byte player = data.BodyIndexData[depthIndex];

                    if (player != 0xff)
                    {
                        int visualIndex = colorIndex * BYTES_PER_PIXEL;

                        data.ResultFramePixels[visualIndex ] = data.ColorData[visualIndex ];
                        data.ResultFramePixels[visualIndex + 1] = data.ColorData[visualIndex  + 1];
                        data.ResultFramePixels[visualIndex + 2] = data.ColorData[visualIndex  + 2];
                        data.ResultFramePixels[visualIndex + 3] = 0xff;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I optimize this code? Is it logical to call CoordinatMapper every time? How i can save association between points once? This looks very strange and not optimized (on my PC CPU - i5 750 2.67GHz this code provides only 15 FPS)

**Important Note:** I'm using emulator Microsoft Kinect Studio for test at the moment not real Kinect. maybe this is the reason?